# Merging arrays defined on different pages using concat

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I have two arrays I want to merge them into one.

```
let signUps = []; 
let usersInputs = [];
```

but each of them has been defined on different pages and therefore when I try

```
        function mergeArray (){
        var merged = signUps.concat(usersInputs);
        document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = merged
        console.warn('added' , [merged] );
        }
```

It says, on this occasion, usersInputs is not defined.

I have encountered this problem on so many occasion, maybe my lack of understanding. so how one approaches this problem?

Answer (score 0):

On different pages you mean it's completely on a separate HTML document and you want to merge them together? In a web page whatever JavaScript you execute is available only inside of that webpage, not on a separate one.

You may either want to store your data on server, or pass it using form data, or best make use of `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` API in JavaScript to pass data from one page to another in a simple way.